# Mongo update query

Tags: mongodb

Hi i need a help for mongo db update query:

For this Data:

```
{
"services" : [ 
        {
             "type" : "Financial Transaction",
        }],
 "outStandingAmount" : 0
}
```

This Query is working fine.

db.getCollection('user_informations').updateMany({"outStandingAmount":},{$set: {"outStandingAmount":5000}})

But when i try to update this I got error.

```
db.getCollection('user_informations').updateMany({"services.type":"Financial Transaction"},{$set: {"services.type":"Financial Trans"}})
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>> You need to make use of the $ operator when you find documents.</strike>

> ```
> db.collection.updateMany(
>    {"services.$.type":"Financial Transaction"},
>    {$set: {"services.type":"Financial Trans"}}
>  )
> ```
>
> update your code and replace `services.type` to `services.$.type` in
>   the **filter** section.

ignore my previous query

this will do it

```
db.collection.find().forEach( function(doc) {
    db.collection.update({"services.type":"Financial Transaction"},
                         {$set:{"services.$.type":"Financial Trans"}});
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection.find().pretty()

{"_id" : ObjectId("5836b428d7e99005c2585b08"), "services" : [{"type" : "Financial Transaction"}],"outStandingAmount" : 0}
{"_id" : ObjectId("5836c5a9d7e99005c2585b09"), "services" : [{"type" : "Financial Transaction"}], "outStandingAmount" : 2000}
```

The below query will do the update on matching records.

```
db.collection.updateMany({"services.type":"Financial Transaction"}, {$set:{
"services":[{"type":"Financial Trans"}]}});
```

Since we had two matching records in our collection 
the result of the above updateMany query is

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 2, "modifiedCount" : 2 }
```

Whereas if we use

```
db.getCollection('user_informations').updateMany({"services.type":"Financial Transaction"},{$set: {"services.type":"Financial Trans"}})
```

we will get an error msg

```
    "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (services of services.type) to traverse the element ({services: [ { type: \"Financial Transaction\" } ]})"
```

When an array is involved then '.' is used to traverse into array elements, even we can traverse into nested arrays using '.', but for modifying an array we have a set of operators, please see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update-array/

also '.' is used on a update query when we use positional operator $.